# Pass A User-Defined Table to a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

I have a User Defined Table that I am passing into a stored procedure from within a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @tmpInput MyTableType;

--Table is populated from an INPUT XML

exec ValidateInputXML SELECT * FROM @tmpInput TI WHERE TI.EntryType = 'Attribute';
```

Now this isn't giving me an error, but when I run a select from with the ValidateInputXML the table has no data.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can also use Table-Valued parameter for your stored procedure. 
E.g.

```
/* Create a table type. */
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE 
( Column1 VARCHAR(50)
, ........ );
GO

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. ValidateInputXML
    @TVP MyTableType READONLY
    AS 
     -- Do what ever you want to do with the table received from caller
    GO

/* Declare a variable that references the type. */
DECLARE @myTable AS MyTableType;

-- Fill @myTable with data and send it to SP. 
insert into @myTable SELECT * FROM @tmpInput TI WHERE TI.EntryType = 'Attribute';


/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */
EXEC ValidateInputXML @myTable ;
GO
```

Comment: I'm not aware if you can pass the recordset directly to Stored procedures without using the table types. Give it another thought.

Comment: This is the style of the solution that we went with.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014. When I run the following, I get an error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE ( Column1 VARCHAR(50));
GO

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the user defined table is in the stored procedure. Once the stored procedure is executed the table `@tmpInput` is created and populated and after that you cannot access it.

From the docs:

> The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the
>   end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

You have two options:

**OPTION 1:**

Create a table in which you can store the records permanently.

**OPTION 2:**

`select` the records from inside the stored procedure like :

```
alter procedure ValidateInputXML 
DECLARE @tmpInput MyTableType;

--Table is populated from an INPUT XML

SELECT * FROM @tmpInput TI WHERE TI.EntryType = 'Attribute';
```

and then

```
exec ValidateInputXML
```