# Why does my stored procedure fail to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having trouble abstracting data using a parameter of table type in my stored procedure below. The data that I am abstracting from consists of over 100 columns/variables. In the stored procedure I focus on four variables: Age_CNT (Age), SEX, ADMSNDT (admission date), and DGNS_CD01 (diagnostic code 1). Variable DGNS_CD01 or diagnostic code 1 has multiple possibilities. For example, in the code below I am looking to abstract records with DGNS_CD01 or diagnostic code value of 390, 391, or 459. Since DGNS_CD01 can have multiple values I declare a variable of type table called @DiseaseCodes and insert values 390, 391, and 459. However, when I execute the stored procedure I find that it does not work with parameter @DiseaseCodes and I cannot figure out why. The other parameters work just fine except @DiseaseCodes

Below is the query with a small sample of fake data. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Any help with the stored procedure would be great! I would love to avoid hard coding it for the specific diagnostic code values because they change based on the request.

```
  --- This is the name of my database.
    USE [Datasets_For_Researchers]
    GO

  --- Here is fake data to run the query below. 
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CMS_Fake_Practice_Data](
[AGE_CNT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SEX] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ADMSNDT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DGNS_CD01] [varchar](50) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CMS_Fake_Practice_Data] (AGE_CNT, SEX, ADMSNDT, DGNS_CD01)
VALUES (66,1,2000344,390), (66,1,2000355,391),(80,2,2000355,500)
GO


    --- According to online articles, I first must initiate type table that 
    --- will be used to store the diagnostic codes I am using to subset the  
    --- data with. 
    CREATE TYPE list_of_three_character_diagnostic_code_tabletype AS TABLE 
   (DiagnosticCodes int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
    GO


   ---The goal of the stored procedure is to simplify data abstraction. 
   ---The most important parameter are the list of diagnostic codes that are  
   ---passed through parameter @DiseaseCodes of type table. 
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data]
  (
    @MinimumAge AS INT = NULL
    , @SelectSex AS INT = NULL
    , @SelectYear AS INT = NULL
    , @DiseaseCodes list_of_three_character_diagnostic_code_tabletype 
     READONLY
    )
AS 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
      CMS_Fake_Practice_Data
    WHERE 
        (@MinimumAge IS NULL OR AGE_CNT >= @MinimumAge) AND
        (@SelectSex IS NULL OR SEX = @SelectSex) AND 
        (@SelectYear IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(ADMSNDT, 1,4) = @SelectYear)) AND 
        (CONVERT(INT, (SUBSTRING( DGNS_CD01, 1, 3))) IN (SELECT 
        DiagnosticCodes FROM @DiseaseCodes))

 END
 GO


    --- Then I declare the table variable @DiseaseCodes and insert values 
    --- that are definitely present in the  CMS_Fake_Practice_Data table. 
    DECLARE @DiseaseCodes AS  list_of_three_character_diagnostic_code_tabletype
    INSERT INTO @DiseaseCodes (DiagnosticCodes)
        VALUES (390),(391),(459)
    GO
```

**EDIT** I updated my code to reflect the suggestions from others but now receive an error stating that @DiseaseCodes was never declared even though it was in the code above.

```
    ---I execute the query with the default setting but retrieve no records. 
    EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes
    GO
```

Comment: Why do you think you are using MySQL with MS Management Studio?   I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You are right. I confused the terms. I'll fix the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass A User-Defined Table to a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515297/pass-a-user-defined-table-to-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting no results because you have

```
 AND 
        (CONVERT(INT, (SUBSTRING( DGNS_CD01, 1, 3))) IN (SELECT 
        DiagnosticCodes FROM @DiseaseCodes))
```

So if you execute the procedure using defaults, then @DiseaseCodes is empty, and nothing is IN the empty table, so you get no results.   The `AND` makes this condition mandatory.

EDIT:

Your latest error is because after you DECLARE and INSERT the `@DiseaseCodes` table, you have a GO.   That ends the batch and destroys the variable.   Then your EXEC is in a new batch where the variable has not been declared.

Take out the GO after the DECLARE/INSERT, and change your EXEC to this:

```
EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes=@DiseaseCodes;
```

Comment: How do I pass the parameter  `@DiseaseCodes` properly in the execution statement? I thought declaring the parameter before the execution was sufficient  and `EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes = (390,391,459)`  or variations of that statement do not work.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=sql+server+how+to+pass+table+to+stored+procedure

Comment: This does not work:`EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes 
GO` I get the following error, "Must declare the scalar variable "@DiseaseCodes"."

Comment: I've already declared the variable as written in the above code. It's like I declare the variable and it doesn't exist yet the declaration line executes successfully. Would you like me to edit the question so that it reflects that the solution does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The only things that jump right out... You cant have a batch separator (GO) between the setting of the TVP and the EXEC Proc, and you have to add the TVP to the proc execution.

So change this...

```
--- Then I declare the table variable @DiseaseCodes and insert values 
--- that are definitely present in the  CMS_Fake_Practice_Data table. 
DECLARE @DiseaseCodes AS  list_of_three_character_diagnostic_code_tabletype
INSERT INTO @DiseaseCodes (DiagnosticCodes)
    VALUES (390),(391),(459)
GO


---I execute the query with the default setting but retrieve no records. 
EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data 
GO
```

... to this...

```
--- Then I declare the table variable @DiseaseCodes and insert values 
--- that are definitely present in the  CMS_Fake_Practice_Data table. 
DECLARE @DiseaseCodes AS  list_of_three_character_diagnostic_code_tabletype
INSERT INTO @DiseaseCodes (DiagnosticCodes)
    VALUES (390),(391),(459);

---I execute the query with the default setting but retrieve no records. 
EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes;
GO
```

Comment: I  need this line `EXEC RetrieveRecords_CMS_1991_2006_Data @DiseaseCodes=@DiseaseCodes; ` for the code to work in addition to removal of the GO. Thanks though!